# Modificar elemento HTML através de funções JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div id="post-0" class="col-md-8 single-publicacoes">
    <div class="index">
        <div class="index-thumbnail">[IMAGE]</div>
        <div id="index-mascara">[EFEITO]</div>
        <div class="index-title-date">
            <p class="title-date">[TEXTO]</p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="post-1" class="col-md-8 single-publicacoes"> ...
```

Instrução jQuery parcial:

```
$(".title-date").on('mouseover', function(){

    // função

}).on('mouseleave', function(){

    // função

});
```

Como, através das funções **mouseover** e **mouseleave** posso fazer o paragrafo `p.title-date` modificar o background de `#index-mascara` lembrando que ele pode modificar só o [elemento corrente](http://escolaaberta.axitech.com.br/noticias/) e não os outros?

Answer (score 1):

Troque de:

```
<div id="index-mascara">[EFEITO]</div>
```

Para:

```
<div class="index-mascara">[EFEITO]</div>
```

E para chegar em ".index-mascara" a partir de ".title-date" use:

```
var mascara = jQuery(this).parent('.index-title-date').prev('.index-mascara');
```

Agora que você tem acesso ao elemento basta aplicar as ações que quiser.